# I am able to get the folders from ALM , but not the tests - c#

Tags: c#, integration, alm

I am trying to read the list of test in particular folder in ALM. It gets the subfolders but not able to read the test cases. No failure is coming, it is just not entering the second foreach loop

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TDConnection con = createConnection("", "", "", "");
        TreeManager TreeMgr = con.TreeManager;
        var SubjRoot = TreeMgr.get_NodeByPath(@"Subject\Regression");
        TestFactory TestFact = SubjRoot.TestFactory;
        var SubjectNodeList = SubjRoot.FindChildren("", false, "");

        foreach (var node in SubjectNodeList)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(node.path);


            var TestFilter = TestFact.Filter;
            TestFilter.Filter["TS_SUBJECT"] = @"""" + node.path + @"""";
            var TestList = TestFact.NewList(TestFilter.Text);
            foreach (var oTest in TestList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Test Name=" + oTest.Name + "' Test Type=" + oTest.Type);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: I got the solution for this. TestFactory TestFact = SubjRoot.TestFactory should be inside the foreach loop for subfolders TestFactory TestFact = node .TestFactory